# Expectation of the Reciprocal

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am actually confused by the term $E\big((1+X)^{-1}\big)$.

> Considering throwing a die twice, Let $X$ be the number of times ($0$, $1$ or $2$), that the number facing up was more than $4$. The expectation reciprocal of $1+X$, namely $E\big((1+X)^{-1}\big)$ is _______?

My work so far:

$X=0$:
First die: {$1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$}; second die: {$1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$}

$X=1$:
First die: {$1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$}; second die: {$5$ or $6$}

or: First die: {$5$ or $6$}; second die: {$1$ or $2$ or $3$ or $4$}

$X=2$:
First die: {$5$ or $6$}; second die: {$5$ or $6$}

Then

$f(0)=16/36$

$f(1)=16/36$

$f(2)=4/36$

$E(X) = (0)(16/36) + (1)(16/36) + (2)(4/36)
=2/3$

$E(1+X) = (1)(16/36) + (2)(16/36) + (3)(4/36)
=5/3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_1$ be the result of the first die toss and $X_2$ the second. They are obviously independent and equally distributed. Namely, $P(X_1=i) = \frac{1}{6}$, $i\in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Now the times we get a number bigger than 4 is given by the new random variable
$$X = 1_{\{X_1>4\}}+1_{\{X_2>4\}},$$
where $1$ denotes the indicator function. Now the distribution of $Z$ is easy.
$$P(X=0)= P(1_{\{X_1>4\}}+1_{\{X_2>4\}}=0)=P(X_1\leq 4, X_2\leq 4)=P(X_1\leq 4)P(X_2\leq 4) = \frac{2}{3}\frac{2}{3} = \frac{4}{9}.$$
Further,
$$P(X=1)= P(1_{\{X_1>4\}}+1_{\{X_2>4\}}=1)=P(X_1>4, X_2\leq 4)+P(X_1\leq 4, X_2> 4)=2\frac{2}{3}\frac{1}{3}= \frac{4}{9},$$
and
$$P(X=2)= P(1_{\{X_1\leq 4\}}+1_{\{X_2\leq 4\}}=0)=P(X_1> 4, X_2> 4)=P(X_1> 4)P(X_2> 4) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{9}.$$
The sum is obviously 1. Now by definition of expectation we have

$$E[(1+X)^{-1}] = (1+0)^{-1} P(X=0)+(1+1)^{-1} P(X=1)+(1+2)^{-1} P(X=2).$$
Substituting,
$$E[(1+X)^{-1}] = 1 \frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{2} \frac{4}{9}+\frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{9}=\frac{19}{27}.$$

Note/comment: Imagine that finding the distribution of $X$ was very difficult. You actually don't need the distribution of $X$ to find the expectation. You can apply the definition of expectation directly on $X_1$ and $X_2$. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
E[(1+ 1_{\{X_1>4\}}+1_{\{X_2>4\}})^{-1}]&=\sum_{i=1}^6 \sum_{j=1}^6 (1+ 1_{\{i>4\}}+1_{\{j>4\}})^{-1} P(X_1=i)P(X_2=j)\\
&=\frac{1}{36}\sum_{i=1}^6 \sum_{j=1}^6 (1+ 1_{\{i>4\}}+1_{\{j>4\}})^{-1}\\
&=\frac{19}{27}.
\end{align*}

Of course, in this case it was easier to first find the distribution of $X$ and then compute the expectation of the random variable $(1+X)^{-1}$.
I hope this helped, good luck!

Comment: hey! thanks for the prompt answer! I tried a few times before this and was finally managed to get the same answer as yours :P

Comment: I'm happy to hear that! Good work :)

Answer (score 0):

You have already computed $P(X=i)$ for $i=0,1,2$, and computed the expectations of $X$ and $1+X$, great! You are asked to compute the expectation of $\frac{1}{1+X}$, so the definition of expectation tells you that
$$E\left(\frac{1}{1+X}\right)=\sum_{i=0}^2\left[P(X=i)\cdot\frac{1}{1+i}\right].$$
Can you verify this, and finish from here?

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution is the following (you already calculated it correctly)

$$X =
\begin{cases}
\frac{4}{9},  & \text{if $x=0$} \\
\frac{4}{9},  & \text{if $x=1$} \\
\frac{1}{9},  & \text{if $x=2$} 
\end{cases}$$

Substituting you get

$$Y=\frac{1}{1+X} =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{9},  & \text{if $y=\frac{1}{3}$} \\
\frac{4}{9},  & \text{if $y=\frac{1}{2}$} \\
\frac{4}{9},  & \text{if $y=1$} 
\end{cases}$$

Now I think it is easy for you to conclude

Answer (score 0):

The distribution of $X$ is binomial with $N=2,p=\frac13,q=\frac23$. Hence the requested expectation

$$\left(\dfrac23\right)^2\frac{1}{1+0}+2\left(\dfrac13\right)\left(\dfrac23\right)\frac{1}{1+1}+\left(\dfrac13\right)^2\dfrac{1}{1+2}=\frac{19}{27}.$$